# Admob Interstitial & Rewarded Ads in Xamarin.from

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

How to show Interstitial and Rewarded Ads in cross platform Xamarin.form application ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own implementation you have to create a dependency service, also already exists a lot of NuGet to show Ads. take a look on this, this package works perfectly to me. https://github.com/LosXamarinos/Xamarinos.AdMob.FormsPlugin

Comment: Please tell how to implement this NuGet package . I read ReadMe file but there is nothing described well.

Comment: Yes, the description and how to use it is there in the ReadMe File, do you know how to add NuGet Packages to your project ? is this your question ?

Comment: If you check ReadMe file , you will find the code bellow   "##Usage  ###Banner Control  var myBanner = new AdBanner();  //Set Your AdMob Key myBanner.AdID = Strings.AdMobKey; ###Interstitial  await CrossAdmobManager.Current.Show ();"            I just want to ask where to put his code for Both banner and Interstitial , in my ContentPage ?

Comment: AdBanner is a View and you have to added into you ContentPage like the other views that you have for example button, entry,listview,etc.. 
 AdBanner  MyyBanner = new AdBanner(); myBanner.AdID = Strings.AdMobKey; yourMainContentView(StackLayout,Grid...).Children.Add(MyBanner); and to show Interstitial Ads just call the method where ever you want, It could be in a button handler and will be displayed Interstitial ads in the screen.